# Build a simple web server that I can run as a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, c++, com, windows-services

I'm a web developer so all my experience is with ruby, python, or PHP. However, I'm gonna do a little windows programming.

I want to build a light weight web server that can handle incoming requests and pass them on to a COM port. I want to be able to distribute it as an exe that will install the server as a windows service.

What do you think would be the best language to do this in? What IDE would be best for said language?

Thanks,
Seth

Comment: google for open source web services in C#, there are some. then customize it. it will be much easier then writing your own.

Comment: @Andrey - Who knows, they may be up to the challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest you will probably have the most fun doing this in C#. The learning curve will be smaller and the language and most of its features are your friend. The fact that you can set up a windows service in 2 minutes is also a plus.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -

Can i set this up so the end user can just run the exe and it will install the service? I don't want the user to have to use the command line to register the service, b/c I'm pretty sure my users aren't going to have the technical ability to do that.

Answer (score 2):

C# and Visual Studio should be fine for this. C# can be compiled/linked into a .exe, and you can make this into a service [very simply](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007am/window_service.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the source code of Cassini. It's actually the built in server over Visual Studio. It might give you some good ideas to get started with: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119154042/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dmitryr/archive/2006/03/09/548131.aspx).

Grz, Kris.